# How to Convert Soundcloud API Responses into CSV in Python?

Tags: python, csv, soundcloud

I, a newbie, am playing around with the Soundcloud API in Python, and when I get a chunk of data in return (as an object, I'm guessing) I am not really sure how to manipulate it:

```
favorites = client.get('/me/favorites')
<class 'soundcloud.resource.ResourceList'>
```

I'm guessing this is sort of of a package of data, which has its own attributes.  I can do:

```
for favorite in favorites:
    print favorite.id
```

And this will give me a list of the IDs of the songs I have favorited.

```
146967741
136766472
```

But, how can I see what attributes this object has for me to play with, and more importantly, how can I convert this into a CSV that I can look into?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using soundcloud-python you can use the `fields` method to get the internal dict or `keys` to just look at the available names.
Source: [resource.py](https://github.com/soundcloud/soundcloud-python/blob/master/soundcloud/resource.py)

As for the csv question, it would be helpful to have more information about what you've already tried, but you could use the csv module's `DictWriter` class, and pass it the dictionaries from `fields()`. More details are available in the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter).

Putting the two together:

```
import csv
with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = favorites[0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()

    for favorite in favorites:
        writer.writerow(favorite.fields())
```

Keep in mind I haven't tested this and I don't have an API key. The [SoundCloud API Guide](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide) also has a wealth of valuable information.

Comment: Thanks!  So the data coming back from soundcloud, what format could you say it's in?  It's not JSON, right?  So I can't look at this from the perspective of converting JSON into CSV (unless I just straight hit up the API via HTTP) is that right?

Comment: If you look at the resource.py link, you'll see the code that translates the incoming request into the ResourceList.  The data coming back is indeed a JSON string, which is being converted to a dict() by the json module function `loads()` [ref](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: Ahh!  This is helpful!  I didn't think to look at the source of Soundcloud's wrapper!  Thanks, I'll take a deeper look :)

Answer (score 0):

As any other object.

```
for favorite in favorites:
    print dir(favorite)
```

There are many modules in the python world such as [csv module (python standard library)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

Comment: Thanks!  How can I describe the format that this data object sits in?  So that I can understand how to convert the sub-sets of this object into CSV?